# What angle is it asking for? How would i find it?

Tags: trigonometry

Worksheet Question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH9bF.png

My Diagram:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfJ0P.jpg

What angle is it asking me to find? im really confused as to how im supposed to find it. Did i draw my diagram right? or did i label it wrong.

Note: I didn't add in all the numbers, i just threw the prism together real quick in paint

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to transcribe the original question, and please embed the image of your diagram in the post rather than including a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably drawn it wrong. Presumably, $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are supposed to be the parallel edges of the prism.

Comment: Also, the person who set the question writes math in English poorly. He should speak of the "length of a segment," not the "distance of a line."

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be talking about the base of the prism.

Then you have to ask which base: BCFE, ACFD, or ABED?

I think if you consider those possibilities, then you will find one is degenerate and the other two are indistinguishable.